# How do I change the settings of zonejs ,handling the error and Zone Scheduling in Angular 12?

Tags: angular, typescript

I can change the settings of zone by configuring them in a separate file and import it just after zonejs import. For example, I can disable the requestAnimationFrame() monkey patch to prevent change detection for no data update as one setting and prevent DOM events(a mousemove or scroll event) to trigger change detection. Let's say the new file named zone-flags.js,

> // disable patching requestAnimationFrame (window as
> any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true;
>
> // disable patching specified eventNames (window as
> any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove'];

But unable to do the error handling and Zone Scheduling. Please help on this.